# python regex validator for repetitive character

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am struggling to write regex pattern.
I want, `It must NOT have  or more consecutive repeated digits.`

```
5133-3367-8912-3456 
so it should return false, Consecutive digits are repeating 4 or more times


5123-4567-8912-3456
and it should return True
```

my code now: `re.match('[0-9]{4}', string)`

I can do with many way in python but i want to do with regex as my case is very different.

Can anyone please help me in this case?

Comment: edited, please check again

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in python with a negative lookahead:

```
^(?![\d-]*(\d)(?:-?\1){3})\d+(?:-\d+)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fNP9pt/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?![\d-]*(\d)(?:-?\1){3})`: Negative lookahead to fail the match when we find 4 repeats of the same digit *optionally* preceded by a single `-`
- `\d+(?:-\d+)*`: Match digits sets delimited by `-`
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all hyphens first, you can use a positive lookahead to search for a repeating pattern for a specified number of times.

```
if re.search(r"(\d)(?=\1{3})", string):
    # Successful match -> This would be your false case
else:
    # Match attempt failed -> This would be your true case
```